# get client IP in socket programming in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, networking

I'm using PHP to write a using socket library application. How could I get the IP of the client? THanks for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use  [socket_getpeername](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-getpeername.php)

Answer (score -6):

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    $visitorIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
    $visitorIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    $visitorIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else
    $visitorIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

?>
```

For more/discussion -
[getting  visitor's real IP address](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2009/10/getting-visitor-ip-address-real-php.html)

Comment: man your article is terrible. this variable can NOT hold the private LAN IP address. While other variables can contain NASDAQ quotes. And all these variables has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Post like this make baby Jesus cry