# Get ip from sender it

Tags: php

So I have a php script, which uses sockets. I want to get the IP from the socket witch sent the data, but so far I only manage to get the IP from the socket reading it, which is always the computer that runs the script.

Is there a way to do it in php using socket_* functions, or do I have to find a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP:

- [`socket_getpeername()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-getpeername.php)
- [`socket_recvfrom()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recvfrom.php)

Sockets: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php

Full documentation: http://php.net/docs.php

Answer (score 0):

use [socket_getpeername()](http://socket_getpeername)

get more information in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794917/get-client-ip-in-socket-programming-in-php) .